# Wordpress Install error on home PC localhost

Tags: wordpress

Im receiving an error on installing the latest Wordpress (4.5) on my home win 8.1 machine with WampServer. Ive installed WP many years ago without issue and not a noob to browser installs but this issue is baffling. The error is in the initial connection to a newly created db for WP and reads ...

> Can’t select database We were able to connect to the database server
>   (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to
>   select the bib_backinbusiness database.
>
> Are you sure it exists? Does the user bib_usrmnrg have permission to use
>   the bib_backinbusiness database? On some systems the name of your
>   database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like
>   username_bib_backinbusiness. Could that be the problem? If you don’t
>   know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all
>   else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.

Funnily enough i encountered this issue when attempting to install OpenCart on my local machine a few months ago and i ended up having to remove the underscore which solves things, However, on shared hosts (as stated in the WP message above) your hosting username is usually prefixed to the DB-name and DB-username.

If i remove the underscore char no doubt it will all work fine but this isn't the issue... both OpenCart installer and WP installers have problems with underscores in DB names. My question: is there a setting (maybe in php.ini) that will override this; though i dont really think its that cos the issue seems to be with the installers.

If i were installing on a production server no doubt the issue would not arise, yet its the same installation script being run, so where is the problem here??

BTW: i also tried adding an escape char right before the underscore in the DB name in wp-config.php  - thus: bib_backinbusiness. The problem persists with the underscore echoed out within the same error message.

Any ideas from anyone ecnountered the same issue?

Comment: Do You have created a mysql db?
You can try to check with a db graphic tool like phpmyadmin or with cli commands, if the name you give to the db match with wordpress config.

Comment: Obviously ... the db exists the username and the password are linked to the db properly using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Solved : i added the db collate key (in wp-config.php):
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

changed to : define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
as read directly from phpMyAdmin db definition.